# Wait for function to finish before running it again

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am connected to a websocket server that receives alerts. I have a function that essentially shows the alert. Now I can receive multiple alerts within a second but the function is suppose to display information for 6 seconds. How do I make it where the function waits until it is finished before running again?

```
function newAlert() {
    console.log('New Alert')
}


///Websocket gets new alert message
newAlert()
```

Comment: You probably won't to throttle the function - see this [article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

Comment: Answers provided will *throw away* any alerts during that 6 seconds - is that what you want? Personally, I'd probably want to see all alerts.  "*but supposed to display for 6 seconds*" - you've not shown how you "display the alert" - and that's where the answer lies; not in discarding alerts - so could be eg you have a single `<div>` and you're replacing that div content each time.  Instead, add a new div and then timeout remove that div.  Put the div in a scrollable container and you get all the alerts shown for 6 seconds.  If you include how you show the alert, then I/we can expand on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a timer or timeout in JavaScript. Here's an example:

```
let isAlertShowing = false;

function newAlert() {
  if (!isAlertShowing) {
    console.log('New Alert');
    isAlertShowing = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      isAlertShowing = false;
    }, 6000); // Wait for 6 seconds before resetting the flag
  }
}

// Websocket gets new alert message
newAlert();
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the function waits for 6 seconds before running again, you can use a combination of a boolean flag and a setTimeout() function. Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates this approach:

```js
let canShowAlert = true;

function showAlert(message) {
  if (canShowAlert) {
    console.log(message);
    canShowAlert = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      canShowAlert = true;
    }, 6000);
  }
}

// Example usage
websocket.on('message', (message) => {
  showAlert(message);
});
```